# Distributed management tool for windows

Tags: windows, remote

I'm searching for a (free, possibly) tool that would let me manage remotely a group of Windows 10 machines (say execute a .bat file, deploy a configuration file, start/stop a service, etc.).
The machines involved are a group of about 20 hosts.

Which is the best tool for this task?
Thanks

Comment: Requests for product, service, or learning material recommendations are off-topic because they attract low quality, opinionated and spam answers, and the answers become obsolete quickly. Instead, describe the business problem you are working on. but pstools can do this

Comment: @djdomi I'm trying to do what I described. We have around 20 machines with some software, and I wish to manage this software (for example, run a .bat file, start/stop a service, etc.) remotely and possibly with an orchestration tool. Thanks

Comment: Software recommendations are offtopic